# Combine the attributes from two different columns to create a single attribute

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in long table format like this:

| ID | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | dry |
| 1 | b | 165 |
| 1 | a | pine |
| 1 | b | 677 |
| 1 | a | moist |
| 1 | b | 251 |
| 2 | a | pine |
| 2 | b | 804 |

**About data:** The value from the second row **165** corresponds to the value **dry** from the first row. Similarly, the value from the fourth row **677** corresponds to the value **pine** from the third row and so on..
In simple words, values for name **b** are related with name **a**.

I want to combine the value in such a way that I could get the corresponding values for each name:

| ID | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | b_dry | 165 |
| 1 | b_pine | 677 |
| 1 | b_moist | 251 |
| 2 | b_pine | 804 |

PS: I am new here, and if anyone finds out that the similar question is answered already, please help me out. I am sorry that I couldn’t make a reproducible example for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(name = str_c(lead(name),value, sep = '_'), value = lead(value)) %>% 
filter(str_detect(name, '^b'))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
     ID name    value
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>
1     1 b_dry   165  
2     1 b_pine  677  
3     1 b_moist 251  
4     2 b_pine  804
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works and you saved my day I would say.

Comment: Hi @Karthik, it would be great if you could have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67057198/combine-attributes-from-two-columns-and-sum-the-values-from-duplicate-rows). This question is slightly modified from this one here.