# Combine attributes from two columns and sum the values from duplicate rows

Tags: r, dataframe

This question is slightly modified from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67022882/combine-the-attributes-from-two-different-columns-to-create-a-single-attribute).

I have a dataframe in long table format like this:

```rb
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
                  name=c("a","c","a","c","a","c","a","c"),
                  value=c("broad",50,"mangrove",50,"mangrove",50,"coniferous",50))
```

```
ID name       value
1    a        broad
1    c           50
1    a     mangrove
1    c           50
1    a     mangrove
1    c           50
2    a   coniferous
2    c           50
```

**About the data:** The value from the second row **50** corresponds to the value **broad** from the first row. Similarly, the value from the fourth row **50** corresponds to the value **mangrove** from the third row and so on.. In simple words, values for name **c** are related with name **a**.

I want to combine the value in such a way that I could get the corresponding values for each name, which would also aggregate the values with similar names:

```rb
df2 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2),
                  name=c("c_broad","c_mangrove","c_coniferous"),
                  value=c(50,100,50))
```

which should look like this:

```
ID         name    value
1       c_broad       50
1    c_mangrove      100
2  c_coniferous       50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *reshape2*:

```
library(reshape2)

df1$grp = cumsum(df1$name == "a")
df2 = dcast(df1, ID + grp ~ name)
df2$c = as.numeric(df2$c)

aggregate(c ~ ID + a, df2, sum)

  ID          a   c
1  1      broad  50
2  2 coniferous  50
3  1   mangrove 100
```

Column names can be changed if desired, also "c_" can be added to the names with paste.

Answer (score 1):

Using tidyverse:

```
value_a <- df1 %>% dplyr::filter(name=="a") %>% dplyr::pull(value) 
df1 %>%
  dplyr::filter(name=="c") %>% #Modify into a sensible data frame from here
  dplyr::mutate(a = value_a,
         name = stringr::str_c(name, "_" ,a)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-a) %>% # to here
  dplyr::group_by(ID, name) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(value=sum(as.numeric(value)))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID name         value
  <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
1     1 c_broad         50
2     1 c_mangrove     100
3     2 c_coniferous    50
```

Tha main problem you find in your dataframe is that a single column is containing, names and values, and that is the first thing you should fix. My advice is always modify the original dataframe into a tidy format (https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/tidy-data.html) and from there leverage all tidyverse power, or data.table or your framework of choice.

Notice the temporal variable value_a could be included in the pipeline directly I have not done it for clarity. The main idea is to separate values and species in different columns, the first three calls in the pipeline, and then apply the usual tidyverse operations.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most elegant, but it works:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
                  name=c("a","c","a","c","a","c","a","c"),
                  value=c("broad",50,"mangrove",50,"mangrove",50,"coniferous",50)
)

df1 %>% group_by( 1+floor((1:n()-1)/2) ) %>%
    summarize(
        ID = ID[1],
        name = paste0( name[2], "_", value[1] ),
        value = as.numeric(value[2])
    ) %>% ungroup %>% select( -1 ) %>% group_by(name) %>%
    mutate( value = sum(value) ) %>%
    unique
```

Here is somthing improved, that actually is humanly readable:

```r
i <- seq( 1, nrow(df1), 2 )
df1 %>% summarise(
            ID = ID[i],
            name = paste0( name[i+1], "_", value[i] ),
            value = as.numeric(value[i+1])
        ) %>% group_by(name) %>%
    summarize(
        ID=ID[1], value = sum( value )
    ) %>% arrange(ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# Nullify numeric values belonging to a grouping category: grps => character vector
grps <- gsub("\\d+", NA, df1$value)

# Interpolate NA values using prior string value: a => character vector
df1$a <- na.omit(grps)[cumsum(!(is.na(grps)))]

# Split-Apply-Combine aggregation: data.frame => stdout(console)
data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(with(df1, split(df1, a)), function(x){
      y <- transform(subset(x, !grepl("\\D+", value)), value = as.numeric(value))
      setNames(
        aggregate(value ~ ID + a, y, FUN = function(z){sum(z, na.rm = TRUE)}),
        c("ID", "a", "c")
        )
      }
    )
  ), 
row.names = NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

additional option

```r
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
                  name=c("a","c","a","c","a","c","a","c"),
                  value=c("broad",50,"mangrove",50,"mangrove",50,"coniferous",50))

library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  pivot_wider(ID, names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% 
  unnest(c("a", "c")) %>% 
  group_by(ID, name = a) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(as.numeric(c), na.rm = T), .groups = "drop") 

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      ID name       value
#>   <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1     1 broad         50
#> 2     1 mangrove     100
#> 3     2 coniferous    50
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>